# Is there an ipv6 equivalent for net.ipv4.conf.all.route_localnet

Tags: iptables, routing, nat, ipv6, sysctl

Is there an ipv6 equivalent for net.ipv4.conf.all.route_localnet ?
(According to [nftables ip6 route to localhost/ ipv6 nat to loopback](https://serverfault.com/questions/975558/nftables-ip6-route-to-localhost-ipv6-nat-to-loopback), there isn't).

If not, how the use case described in [Port forward with iptables](https://serverfault.com/questions/646522/port-forward-with-iptables) can be solved for ipv6?